# D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetScissorRects

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11

Starting roughly two days ago, every D3D11 application I've run has exploded within the first 30 seconds of being started [including code I've never touched].

I'm using Visual Studios 2013 with the Windows 8.1 SDK installed [reinstalled today for good measure].

Since it's a D3D error, it only explodes in Debug, but a crash somewhere is a problem somewhere else.

`D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetScissorRects: First parameter out of range. [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #13: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER1]`

I've never used `ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetScissorRects` for any purpose ever. I don't even know what parameters it takes in, spits out, what it does or any combination of otherwise.

Since there's a `ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetScissorRects` I assume there's a `ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetScissorRects` as well, but as with `ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetScissorRects`, I don't know what it does.

Since it's relatively important for me to be able to Graphics, what's the potential solution for this problem?

[This](http://pastebin.com/9D0d6aNa) is my current DirectX11 initialization as it stands.

Members of my team are able to run our DirectX11 Application for hours without problems, but when it's passed to my machine via USB...explosions

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have some knowledge of DirectX11, yet I have never used that interface either. I looked at your source and everything appears to be okay. However a few questions that need to be answered: What versions of Windows are you working on? Does the machine have a DirectX11 capable video card and if so what manufacture is the card or is it running from on board video? Is machine a desktop, laptop or tablet etc.?

Comment: What OS version are you using?  Also, in `C:\Windows\System32` (or `SysWOW64` if you're running a 32-bit process), what versions of `d3d11*sdklayers.dll` do you have?  And if you right-click each one, what are the values of Properties > Details > File version?

Comment: If you're seeing this API cause an error even if you're not calling it then is it possible you have inadvertently recently installed an overlay? Such examples might Fraps, AMD Gaming Evolved (AMD's Capture/Broadcast tool that comes with their drivers), Nvidia's Shadowplay, perhaps even the Steam Overlay. If they've hooked your device then you'll likely see RSGetScissorRects being called inside 'Present'.

Comment: @AdamMiles yes, actually. AMD's Gaming Evolved forced itself down my throat a couple months back; and you're correct. When the break occurs, a Present call had just occurred.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I'm using an HP Elitebook 8770w [Business Class Workstation (Laptop)] running Windows 7 with an AMD FirePro M4000 [FireGL] (DirectX11.1 compatible) Graphics Card.

Comment: @MooseBoys it would appear i have `d3d11_1sdklayers.dll` and `d3d11_2sdklayers.dll`. The version of the former is `9.30.960.9200`, and the latter `9.30.9600.17336`

Comment: Does the debugger stop at the point that the error occurs? If so you should be able to pull up a call stack and see which DLL it was in last. My guess is that it comes from your application but before reaching D3D it'll go via some 3rd party DLL. Can you post a full call-stack at the point that the error occurs?

Comment: @AdamMiles [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw7da025s3li1l0/Screenshot%202015-05-13%2009.49.51.png?dl=0) that's all that's there, unless there's a different Call Stack somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, in your call stack "ltc_game32" appears to be attributable to Raptr, which is part of AMD Gaming Evolved. This has hooked your D3D11 application to provide some sort additional capture/record functionality and appears not to run "clean" with regards to the D3D11 Debug Layer.

Try uninstalling Raptr from the Control Panel to remove this additional "feature" of the driver and see if the problem continues to occur. It may also be sufficient to simply close AMD Gaming Evolved from your task tray and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: You're right; closing AMD Gaming Evolved from the Task Tray was the fix. Many Thanks! I appreciate it.